# How to to solve inequality $(a+b\cos x)^2+(c \sin x)^2\leq 1$ for any $x$?

Tags: inequalities

Does Mathematica have the ability to solve this inequality:

```
(a + b * Cos[x])^2 + (c * Sin[x])^2 <= 1
```

for any `x ∈ [0, 2*Pi]`?

The answer should contain conditions/inequalities for `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: Assuming the variables are real, Reduce[(a + b*Cos[x])^2 + (c*Sin[x])^2 <= 1, Reals] gives an answer.

Comment: @bills: No, it is not true. If you execute the code suggested by you, you'll see `(a == -1 - bCos[x] && 
   cSin[x] == 0) || (-1 - bCos[x] < a < 
    1 - bCos[x] && -Sqrt[1 - a^2 - 2 a bCos[x] - bCos[x]^2] <= 
    cSin[x] <= Sqrt[1 - a^2 - 2 a bCos[x] - bCos[x]^2]) || (a == 
    1 - bCos[x] && cSin[x] == 0)`.

Comment: @user64494 Bill S meant `Reduce[(a + b*Cos[x])^2 + (c*Sin[x])^2 <= 1 && 0 <= x <= 2 \[Pi], {a, 
  b, c}, Reals]` .  The implicit multiplications disappeared during the copy-and-paste.

Comment: @IAmANaïf: This results in `(x == 0 && -1 - a <= b <= 1 - a) || (0 < x < \[Pi]/
    2 && ((b == (-1 - a) Sec[x] && 
       c == 0) || ((-1 - a) Sec[x] < 
        b < (1 - a) Sec[
          x] && -\[Sqrt]((1 - a^2 - 2 a b Cos[x] - b^2 Cos[x]^2) Csc[
             x]^2) <= c <= 
        Sqrt[(1 - a^2 - 2 a b Cos[x] - b^2 Cos[x]^2) Csc[
          x]^2])... <= 
        Sqrt[(1 - a^2 - 2 a b Cos[x] - b^2 Cos[x]^2) Csc[x]^2])`

Comment: @user64494 I am confused as I do not understand your point. I posted that full answer (and it is an answer to the question as asked as I understand the question).

Answer (score 3):

You could calculate the extremal points of $m(x)=(a+b\cos x)^2+(c\sin x)^2$ and make sure they are all smaller than 1:

```
m[x_] = (a + b*Cos[x])^2 + (c*Sin[x])^2;
m[x] /. Solve[m'[x] == 0, x] // FullSimplify // Union

(*    {(a + b)^2 if ...,
       (a - b)^2 if ...,
       (c^2 (a^2 - b^2 + c^2))/(-b^2 + c^2) if ...}    *)
```

where the conditions (`if ...`) are trivial and don't affect the result. So we can say that

$$
m(x)\le\max\left((a + b)^2,(a - b)^2,\frac{c^2 (a^2 - b^2 + c^2)}{c^2-b^2}\right)
$$

and the inequality is satisfied if

$$
\max\left((a + b)^2,(a - b)^2,\frac{c^2 (a^2 - b^2 + c^2)}{c^2-b^2}\right)\le1
$$

Let's define a Region that satisfies these constraints:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[(a - b)^2 <= 1 &&
                   (a + b)^2 <= 1 &&
                   (c^2 (a^2 - b^2 + c^2))/(c^2 - b^2) <= 1,
                   {a, b, c}];

RegionPlot3D[R, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {a, b, c}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

### update

[As Ulrich Neumann shows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285162/26598), the above condition is sufficient, but not necessary, for having $m(x)\le1\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. For example, $(a,b,c)=(\frac38, \frac{11}{32}, \frac38)$ does not satisfy my conditions because $\frac{c^2(a^2-b^2+c^2)}{c^2-b^2}=\frac{1503}{1472}>1$. However, this maximum is not achieved on the reals, but rather for $x=2.43278i$ on the imaginary axis.

Comment: Unfortunately, `m[x]` (in your notation) can take values greater than 1 for some `a`,`b`, and `c`.

Comment: @user64494 you're just trolling. Good luck!

Comment: Roman (@ does not work): Unfortunately, your reply is not constructive and polite.

Comment: Roman (@ does not work):  Your claim "However, this maximum is not achieved on the reals" does not correspond to reality in view of `a = 3/8; b = 11/32; c = 3/8;Maximize[{(a + b*Cos[x])^2 + (c*Sin[x])^2, x >= 0 && x <= 2*Pi}, x]` which results in `{529/1024, {x -> 0}}`.

Comment: Roman (@ does not work):  I think the reason for your answer to be only partial is the following: critical points may be inflection points, not only extremal points.

Comment: Roman (@ does not work):  Try to select the critical points where `m''[x]!=0`. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

One may try

```
Resolve[ForAll[x,x>=0&&x<=2*Pi, (a+b*Cos[x])^2+(c*Sin[x])^2<=1],Reals]
```

Unfortunately, this simple-minded approach does not work. As [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html#8610) says,

> Resolve can always eliminate quantifiers from any collection of polynomial equations and inequations over complex numbers, and from any collection of polynomial equations and inequalities over real numbers

So we reduce the problem to a polynomial inequality in such a way

```
Resolve[ForAll[{cos, sin}, sin^2 + cos^2 == 1, (a + b*cos)^2 + (c*sin)^2 <= 1], Reals]
```

> `(a == 0 &&  a^2 + b^2 <= 1 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 &&  a^2 + c^2 <= 1) || (b ==  0 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 &&  a^2 + c^2 <= 1) || (a^2 + b^2 <=  1 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 && b - c == 0 && a^2 + c^2 <= 1) || (a^2 + b^2 <=  1 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 && b + c == 0 && a^2 + c^2 <= 1) || (a^2 + b^2 <=  1 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 &&  a^2 + c^2 <= 1 &&  b^2 + a^2 b^2 - b^4 - c^2 + a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2 > 0) || (a^2 + b^2 <= 1 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 &&  a^2 + c^2 <= 1 && b^2 - c^2 + a^2 c^2 - b^2 c^2 + c^4 <= 0)`

Addition. In fact, the answer of @UlrichNeumann coincides with my answer.

```
cond = Resolve[ForAll[u, (a + b*Cos[x])^2 + (c*Sin[x])^2 <= 1 /. x -> 2 ArcTan[u] //TrigExpand], Reals]
```

> `(a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 < 1 && a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 <= 1 &&  b^2 - c^2 + a^2 c^2 - b^2 c^2 + c^4 <= 0) || (a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 <  1 && a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 <=  1 && -b^2 + a^2 b^2 - b^4 + c^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 + a^4 c^2 +  4 b^2 c^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 c^2 + b^4 c^2 - 3 c^4 + 3 a^2 c^4 -  3 b^2 c^4 + 2 c^6 < 0) || (a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 <= 1 &&  a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 <= 1 &&  a^2 - b^2 + 2 c^2 <=  1 && -b^2 + a^2 b^2 - 2 a b^3 + b^4 + c^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 + a^4 c^2 +  2 a b c^2 - 2 a^3 b c^2 + 2 a b^3 c^2 - b^4 c^2 - c^4 +  a^2 c^4 - 2 a b c^4 + b^2 c^4 >= 0) || (a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 <= 1 && a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 <= 1 && a^2 - b^2 + 2 c^2 < 1 &&  b^2 - c^2 + a^2 c^2 - b^2 c^2 + c^4 > 0)`

and

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c},  Equivalent[cond, (a == 0 && 
  a^2 + b^2 <= 1 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 &&
   a^2 + c^2 <= 1) || (b == 
   0 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 && 
  a^2 + c^2 <= 1) || (a^2 + b^2 <= 
   1 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 && 
  b - c == 0 && 
  a^2 + c^2 <= 1) || (a^2 + b^2 <= 
   1 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 && 
  b + c == 0 && 
  a^2 + c^2 <= 1) || (a^2 + b^2 <= 
   1 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 && 
  a^2 + c^2 <= 1 && 
  b^2 + a^2 b^2 - b^4 - c^2 + a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2 > 
   0) || (a^2 + b^2 <= 
   1 && -2 a^2 + a^4 - 2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 >= -1 && 
  a^2 + c^2 <= 1 && b^2 - c^2 + a^2 c^2 - b^2 c^2 + c^4 <= 0)]],Reals]
```

> `True`

Comment: The full simplification of the above does nothing.

Comment: a little additional question: i watch the help page of Resolve[] and Reduce[], seems Reduce[] can also do what Resolve[] does, seems Reduce[] is upper-substitution of Resolve[], right?

Comment: @Aerterliusi: Up to [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html?q=Resolve), "Resolve is in effect automatically applied by Reduce".

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Romans answer Weierstrass-transformation `x -> 2 ArcTan[u]` gives a more direct and smooth solution:

```
cond = Resolve[ForAll[u, (a + b*Cos[x])^2 + (c*Sin[x])^2 <= 1 /. x -> 2 ArcTan[u] //TrigExpand], Reals]

    (*(a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 < 1 && a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 <= 1 && 
   b^2 - c^2 + a^2 c^2 - b^2 c^2 + c^4 <= 0) || (a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 < 
    1 && a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 <= 
    1 && -b^2 + a^2 b^2 - b^4 + c^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 + a^4 c^2 + 
     4 b^2 c^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 c^2 + b^4 c^2 - 3 c^4 + 3 a^2 c^4 - 
     3 b^2 c^4 + 2 c^6 < 0) || (a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 <= 1 && 
   a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 <= 1 && 
   a^2 - b^2 + 2 c^2 <= 
    1 && -b^2 + a^2 b^2 - 2 a b^3 + b^4 + c^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 + a^4 c^2 + 
     2 a b c^2 - 2 a^3 b c^2 + 2 a b^3 c^2 - b^4 c^2 - c^4 + 
     a^2 c^4 - 2 a b c^4 + b^2 c^4 >= 0) || (a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 <= 1 &&
    a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 <= 1 && a^2 - b^2 + 2 c^2 < 1 && 
   b^2 - c^2 + a^2 c^2 - b^2 c^2 + c^4 > 0)*)


R = ImplicitRegion[cond, {a, b, c}];
RegionPlot3D[R, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {a, b, c},PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

**addendum( see Roman's update)**

```
cond /. {a -> 3/8, b -> 11/32, c -> 3/8}
(*True*)
```

Comment: This region is more complete than the one found in my solution.

Comment: In fact, your answer coincides with my answer (see the addition to my answer). It would be instantly clear if you present your `cond`.

Comment: @user64494 I added cond in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

13.2.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)
```

```mma
Reduce[(a + b*Cos[x])^2 + (c*Sin[x])^2 <= 1 && 0 <= x <= 2 \[Pi], {a, 
  b, c}, Reals]
```

```mma
(x == 0 && -1 - a <= b <= 1 - a) || 
  (0 < x < Pi/2 && ((b == (-1 - a)*Sec[x] && 
     c == 0) || ((-1 - a)*Sec[x] < b < 
      (1 - a)*Sec[x] && 
     -Sqrt[(1 - a^2 - 2*a*b*Cos[x] - b^2*Cos[x]^2)*
         Csc[x]^2] <= c <= 
      Sqrt[(1 - a^2 - 2*a*b*Cos[x] - b^2*Cos[x]^2)*
        Csc[x]^2]) || (b == (1 - a)*Sec[x] && 
     c == 0))) || (x == Pi/2 && 
   ((a == -1 && c == 0) || (-1 < a < 1 && 
     -Sqrt[1 - a^2] <= c <= Sqrt[1 - a^2]) || 
    (a == 1 && c == 0))) || (Pi/2 < x < Pi && 
   ((b == (1 - a)*Sec[x] && c == 0) || 
    ((1 - a)*Sec[x] < b < (-1 - a)*Sec[x] && 
     -Sqrt[(1 - a^2 - 2*a*b*Cos[x] - b^2*Cos[x]^2)*
         Csc[x]^2] <= c <= 
      Sqrt[(1 - a^2 - 2*a*b*Cos[x] - b^2*Cos[x]^2)*
        Csc[x]^2]) || (b == (-1 - a)*Sec[x] && 
     c == 0))) || (x == Pi && -1 + a <= b <= 
    1 + a) || (Pi < x < (3*Pi)/2 && 
   ((b == (1 - a)*Sec[x] && c == 0) || 
    ((1 - a)*Sec[x] < b < (-1 - a)*Sec[x] && 
     -Sqrt[(1 - a^2 - 2*a*b*Cos[x] - b^2*Cos[x]^2)*
         Csc[x]^2] <= c <= 
      Sqrt[(1 - a^2 - 2*a*b*Cos[x] - b^2*Cos[x]^2)*
        Csc[x]^2]) || (b == (-1 - a)*Sec[x] && 
     c == 0))) || (x == (3*Pi)/2 && 
   ((a == -1 && c == 0) || (-1 < a < 1 && 
     -Sqrt[1 - a^2] <= c <= Sqrt[1 - a^2]) || 
    (a == 1 && c == 0))) || ((3*Pi)/2 < x < 2*Pi && 
   ((b == (-1 - a)*Sec[x] && c == 0) || 
    ((-1 - a)*Sec[x] < b < (1 - a)*Sec[x] && 
     -Sqrt[(1 - a^2 - 2*a*b*Cos[x] - b^2*Cos[x]^2)*
         Csc[x]^2] <= c <= 
      Sqrt[(1 - a^2 - 2*a*b*Cos[x] - b^2*Cos[x]^2)*
        Csc[x]^2]) || (b == (1 - a)*Sec[x] && 
     c == 0))) || (x == 2*Pi && -1 - a <= b <= 1 - a)
```

Comment: Do you pay your attention to the following places of the question "for any `x ∈ [0, 2*Pi]`" and "The answer should contain conditions/inequalities for `a`, `b` and `c`"?

Comment: In your answer you find `a`,`b`,`c` which satisfy `(a + b * Cos[x])^2 + (c * Sin[x])^2 <= 1` for a given `x` from `0` to `2*Pi`. Compare with my answer.